# Looker database connection limits

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I would like to know if is there any query or table size limits when connecting Looker to PostgreSQL databases?
In Looker Studio there's a 150K rows limit, for instance.
Also, an additional (less important) question: if I migrate from Looker Studio to Looker can I keep my dashboards (transfer them from Looker Studio to Looker)?

I have some dashboards in Looker Studio that need automatic update - so I cannot use csv file as data sources. I would like to avoid using Google Sheets so I can better structure my data in a database. As Looker Studio does not use cache, if the BigQuery database/connector is used it will redo the queries each time the filters are changed by any user of the data is refreshed, making the costs very high. So, I'm using a postgreSQL database. However, the postgreSQL connector has a limitation of 150K rows, and I usually need to use more than 500K rows. That's why I'm considering moving to Looker instead -  as I don't know any other solution. Please tell me if you have any suggestions.

Thanks a lot!